# Use of for loop to delete rows of specific instances in R

Tags: r

Could you please let me know know how I could only keep the row with the highest hands for every different players? 
I intended to do a for loop but I could not figure out how to solve it.

Example the only row left for player 1141 should be the one with 23658 hands, the only row left for player 1714 should be the one with 678 hands.

```
  **Player  PKMP ID    Hands** 
    1141    PKMP002    179
    1141    PKMP002    15
    1141    PKMP002    22816
    1141    PKMP002    131
    1141    PKMP002    23658
    1141    PKMP002    4914
    1714    PKMP016    531
    1714    PKMP016    91
    1714    PKMP016    678
    1714    PKMP016    123
    1745    PKMP032    6821
    1745    PKMP032    41
    1745    PKMP032    8
    1745    PKMP032    204
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  filter(Hands == max(Hands))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Player [3]
  Player `PKMP ID` Hands
   <int>    <fctr> <int>
1   1141   PKMP002 23658
2   1714   PKMP016   678
3   1745   PKMP032  6821
```

Answer (score 2):

First the data.

```
Lorenna <- 
structure(list(Player = c(1141L, 1141L, 1141L, 1141L, 1141L, 
1141L, 1714L, 1714L, 1714L, 1714L, 1745L, 1745L, 1745L, 1745L
), PKMP_ID = c("PKMP002", "PKMP002", "PKMP002", "PKMP002", "PKMP002", 
"PKMP002", "PKMP016", "PKMP016", "PKMP016", "PKMP016", "PKMP032", 
"PKMP032", "PKMP032", "PKMP032"), Hands = c(179L, 15L, 22816L, 
131L, 23658L, 4914L, 531L, 91L, 678L, 123L, 6821L, 41L, 8L, 204L
)), .Names = c("Player", "PKMP_ID", "Hands"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Now the code. I will use `sapply` to do all of the work, but then transpose the result with `t()`.

```
L <- t(sapply(split(Lorenna, Lorenna$Player), function(x) x[which.max(x$Hands), ]))
L <- as.data.frame(L)
row.names(L) <- NULL
L
#  Player PKMP_ID Hands
#1   1141 PKMP002 23658
#2   1714 PKMP016   678
#3   1745 PKMP032  6821
```